# Driving costs - functions in python- EOFerror in if __name__ == '__main__':

Tags: python, eoferror

I am stuck with this question:

Write a function driving_cost() with input parameters miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, and miles_driven, that returns the dollar cost to drive those miles. All items are of type float. The function called with arguments (20.0, 3.1599, 50.0) returns 7.89975.

Define that function in a program whose inputs are the car's miles per gallon and the price of gas in dollars per gallon (both float). Output the gas cost for 10 miles, 50 miles, and 400 miles, by calling your driving_cost() function three times.

Output each floating-point value with two digits after the decimal point, which can be achieved as follows:
print(f'{your_value:.2f}')

Ex: If the input is:

20.0
3.1599
the output is:

1.58 7.90 63.20
Your program must define and call a function:
def driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, miles_driven)

The question also gets evaluated using a direct call of the function like this: `driving_cost(20.0,3.1599, 50.0)` which is the part that is broken.

Here is my code so far:

```
def driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, miles_driven):
    return dollars_per_gallon/miles_per_gallon*miles_driven
    
miles_per_gallon=float(input())
dollars_per_gallon=float(input())

miles=[10, 50, 400]
for i in miles:
    print(f'{driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, i):.2f}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    miles_driven=float(input());
    cost=driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, miles_driven);
    print(f'{cost:.2f}');
```

If I just input values, the top section executes but if I call the function like this `driving_cost(20.0,3.1599, 50.0)` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    miles_per_gallon=float(input())
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'driving_cost(20.0, 3.1599, 50.0)'
```

I don't completely grasp the `if __name__ == '__main__':` thing either but I really don't understand why this error is occurring. Even when I include the other inputs in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` part of the program, I get that error.  Help please?

Comment: You tried passing in a nonsense string as the mpg value. The error seems pretty clear...

Comment: First of all try to minimize the code, to narrow down exactly where it happns and why. For example remove everything but the `driving_cost` function, and a call to it with the exact specified arguments, no input and no `if __name__ == '__main__':`. Just the function definition and the single call `driving_cost(20.0, 3.1599, 50.0)`. If that works then save the result and print it. If that works then add the input for `miles_driven`. And so on, until you get the error back. Then you know that the last bit you added was the cause of the error and can examine that more closely.

Comment: alright.. I printed the result of driving_cost(20.0, 3.1599, 50.0) and the function ran without issue. I added in the inputs again without the loop and printed the driving cost using the input values and it ran. I added my loop back in with only the original 2 inputs as well as my miles and it runs fine. the issue is within that if __name__ == '__main__': section for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

This was a challenge, I ain't going to lie.  I worked on this for hours and the instructions are sloppy to say the least.  I put a default value on miles_driven as a parameter and then just did the math for 10, 50, and 400 miles in the print line at the bottom, calling the function (driving_cost) three times as instructed.

I tried to make a variable for a third input or argument (miles_driven), but it would not accept it for some reason.  Not sure if it is a problem on there end because the instruction made it seem like a third argument would be sometimes inputted, but it never was.

The following code was accepted and marked as complete, so hope it helps.

```
def driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, 
    miles_driven=10.0):
    return (miles_driven / miles_per_gallon) * dollars_per_gallon
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Type your code here.
    miles = float(input())
    dollars = float(input())

    price = driving_cost(miles, dollars) 
    print(f'{price:.2f}')
    print(f'{price * 5:.2f}')
    print(f'{price * 40:.2f}')
```

Comment: A beautifully concise first answer! +1

Answer (score 0):

The traceback is telling you the problem happens on line 4 and shows you the line that caused the problem:

```
miles_per_gallon=float(input())
```

Even though you probably added `driving_cost(20.0,3.1599, 50.0)` somewhere further down, you still have this line in your code and it still takes input, which still has to be a string representing a valid floating point number, or you will get that error.

As for the `if __name__ == '__main__':` part: your script gets executed top to bottom when you run it. But if your script contains some useful functions you'd like to use from some other script, you may way to `import my_script` or `from my_script import driving_cost`.

However, whenever you `import` a module, Python actually *runs* the module. If all the code in the module lives inside functions, that's OK, nothing gets run until a function gets called. But your script does execute all sorts of code.

That's where `if __name__ == '__main__':` comes in. Every script has a `__name__` variable defined. If your script is the main script being run by Python, its `__name__` will be `'__main__'`. So, that line basically says "if this script is being run as the main script, run some code, otherwise (if this script is being run as a module) don't".

As a result, this would be a better way to organise your script:

```py
def driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, miles_driven):
    return dollars_per_gallon / miles_per_gallon * miles_driven


def input_compute_and_print():
    miles_per_gallon = float(input())
    dollars_per_gallon = float(input())

    miles = [10, 50, 400]
    for i in miles:
        print(f'{driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, i):.2f}')


def print_example():
    cost = driving_cost(20.0,3.1599, 50.0)
    print(f'{cost:.2f}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_compute_and_print()
    # print_example()
```

Note that this is just your own code reorganised (without the later changes). By commenting out the calls in the bottom section, you can get separate parts to run.

Comment: Yes, I see that and I understand. The issue is that it executes properly until that if __name__ == '__main__':  bit gets involved which is the reason I am so stuck. If I get rid of the if __name__ == '__main__':  part, the code executes just fine

Comment: If I take the literal code from your example, and run it - it runs just fine, as long as I enter data that makes sense (for example, 20 + Enter, 3.5 + Enter and 20 + Enter again). You probably enter something that doesn't make sense, aren't actually running the code you shared, or have more code outside it you're not sharing.

Comment: An important programming lesson: if you think you know what the problem is, but the problem doesn't get fixed if you change that thing, it's most likely you don't know what the problem is (even though it feels like you do). There's nothing magical about that bit of code, you just need to carefully look at your code and perhaps clean it up a bit - throw out the fluff that you think or know isn't the issue and then only add in the one thing you do think is a problem, to find the problem you're not seeing.

Comment: you are right and I figured out what is happening (hooray shower thoughts). the input variable was reading my whole call of the function as the input which is non-convertible to a float. I get that piece now. I just need to understand how to get the function to evaluate using the values inside the function rather than user 'inputs' in that last section. I see what you added and it is unfamiliar to me but the section on the main calling was short and not helpful so let me try this

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it according to the prompt.

```
def driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, miles_driven):
        dollar_cost = miles_driven * (dollars_per_gallon/miles_per_gallon)
        return(dollar_cost)
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        miles_per_gallon = float(input())
        dollars_per_gallon = float(input())
        print(f'{driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon,miles_driven = 10):.2f}')
        print(f'{driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon,miles_driven = 50):.2f}')
        print(f'{driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon,miles_driven = 400):.2f}')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I created an account just to answer this because it made me so angry. This question is so poorly written and impossible to understand.

here's what I did to pass this test:

```
# def driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, 
#     miles_driven=10.0):
#     return (miles_driven / miles_per_gallon) * dollars_per_gallon

def driving_cost(driven_miles, miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon):
    return (driven_miles / miles_per_gallon) * dollars_per_gallon
    
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    miles = float(input())
    dollars = float(input())

    price = driving_cost(10, miles, dollars) 
    print(f'{price:.2f}')
    print(f'{price * 5:.2f}')
    print(f'{price * 40:.2f}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function DrivingCost(float drivenMiles, float milesPerGallon, float dollarsPerGallon) returns float dollarCost
```

dollarCost = (drivenMiles/milesPerGallon)*dollarsPerGallon

Function Main() returns nothing

float milesPerGallon

float dollarsPerGallon

float cost

milesPerGallon = Get next input

dollarsPerGallon = Get next input

cost = DrivingCost(10,milesPerGallon,dollarsPerGallon)

Put cost to output with 2 decimal places

Put " " to output

cost = DrivingCost(50,milesPerGallon,dollarsPerGallon)

Put cost to output with 2 decimal places

Put " " to output

cost = DrivingCost(400,milesPerGallon,dollarsPerGallon)

Put cost to output with 2 decimal places

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).