# Why is this not working on my Driving costs - functions code

Tags: python

This is the info given for my problem:

> Write a function driving_cost() with input parameters
> miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, and miles_driven, that returns
> the **dollar cost** to drive those miles. All items are of type float.
> The function called with arguments `(20.0, 3.1599, 50.0)` returns
> `7.89975`.
>
> Define that function in a program whose inputs are the car's miles per
> gallon and the price of gas in dollars per gallon (both float). Output
> the gas cost for 10 miles, 50 miles, and 400 miles, by calling your
> driving_cost() function three times.
>
> Output each floating-point value with two digits after the decimal
> point, which can be achieved as follows: `print(f'{your_value:.2f}')`

Whenever I set `miles_driven` to `float(input())` I get an EOF error and nothing happens.
Maybe its just me but I have been stuck on this for a day, I can get it to print using 10,50,and 400 with 3 seperate calls but  I can not get it to work with `miles_driven = float`

```py
# This was the code I last tried

# Define your function here.
miles_per_gallon = float(input())
dollars_per_gallon = float(input())
miles_driven = float(input())


def driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, miles_driven):
    if miles_driven == 'None':
        miles_driven = [10, 50, 400]
        for m in miles_driven:
            cost = (dollars_per_gallon / miles_per_gallon) * miles_driven
            return cost
            print(f'{cost:.2f}')

    else:
        cost = (dollars_per_gallon / miles_per_gallon) * miles_driven
        print(f'{cost:.2f}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Type your code here.

    print(driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, miles_driven))
```

Comment: You appear to be running this code in an environment where `input()` doesn't work normally.  I've seen online Python interpreters where you have to pre-enter all input before running the program, and I've heard of an Android implementation that doesn't seem to support `input()` at all.  So how are you running the code?

Comment: Note that sometimes you are going to run into [Why is this printing 'None' in the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812851/why-is-this-printing-none-in-the-output)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Driving costs - functions in python- EOFerror in if \_\_name\_\_ == '\_\_main\_\_':](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69793245/driving-costs-functions-in-python-eoferror-in-if-name-main)

Comment: If you're running this interactively, the only way (that I know of) to get an EOFError exception is if you type Ctrl-D at the input prompt

Comment: jasonharper - yes the input is pre-enter.  When I go to test it, it needs to work with an input for miles_driven and without.

Comment: jonSG- almost, I got it to work doing that but it needs to work when miles_driven is also a float input and just out put that as the driving cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking for `miles_driven` can be dropped as assignment clearly asks for results for 10, 50 and 400 miles only, so why ask user for that. The `The line if miles_driven == 'None':` check if wrong as it means **string** of value "None" and not `None`. You got unconditional `return cost` that kills the loop as this will always return after first iteration so the next line's `print()` never executes (your IDE should flag that already). This all can be made much simpler:

```py
def driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, miles_driven):
    cost = (miles_driven / miles_per_gallon) * dollars_per_gallon
    return cost

if __name__ == '__main__':
    miles_per_gallon = float(input("Enter the car's miles per gallon: "))
    dollars_per_gallon = float(input("Enter the price of gas per gallon: "))

    for miles in [10, 50, 400]:
        cost = driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, miles)
        print(f'{cost:.2f}')
```

Comment: Write a function driving_cost() with input parameters miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, and miles_driven, that returns the dollar cost to drive those miles. All items are of type float. That is the first information given, and when testing miles_driven is not always given. That is when I want it to use float type input for miles driven

Comment: fine, but both `10` and `10.0` is the same value numerically. But if you want to have float for any reason, just change the loop's `cost = driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, float(miles))` or change the list elements to `[10.0, 50.0, 400.0]`. I see no point in dynamically typed language, but if you need that it's still ok

Answer (score 0):

this is how I wrote it for it to pass all the tests.
Thanks Marcin

def driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, miles_driven):
cost = (dollars_per_gallon / miles_per_gallon) * miles_driven
return cost

if **name** == '**main**':
# Type your code here.

```
miles_per_gallon = float(input())
dollars_per_gallon = float(input())

miles = [10,50,400]
   
print(f'{driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, miles[0]):.2f}')
print(f'{driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, miles[1]):.2f}')
print(f'{driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, miles[2]):.2f}')
```